# ASP.NET MVC 4 Get file input stream before completely filling the server's memory

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am having hard time figuring out how to get the file InputStream from file upload Post request to server, before it gets completely loaded into memory.

This is not problematic for smaller files, but I am worried what happens after trying to upload a larger file (1 or more GB). I found a possible solution with using `HttpContext.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true)`, but this stream includes the whole request not just the uploading file and if I use it to upload a file for example into the Azure Blob Storage or anywhere else I end up with the corrupted file. I also lose all the information about the file (file name, size, etc.).

Is there any convenient way of uploading a large file to server without filling its memory? I would like to get the stream and then use it to upload a file anywhere in chunks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used DevExpress UploadControl for a similar task. It supports [large file upload by chunks](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9822). A temporary file is saved on a server hard drive and you can get it using FileSteam without full loading in server memory. It also supports [direct upload](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/UploadToAzure) to Azure, Amazon and Dropbox. 
The same is true for their MVC Upload control.